# I want to overload "=" operator to assign value from an object to a non class int variable

Tags: c++, overloading, assignment-operator

```
int i;
Integer a; //a class object

i=a; //here a's member variable value should be assigned to 'i'
```

Comment: Here variable `a` is of `class` type and `i` is `int` type, so you should have type cast `a` to `int`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Probably at least partly because there isn't a question in the body, just code.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Maybe someone found that "This question does not show any research effort" ?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I can see how this is not trivial to find unless you know what to look for.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=overload+operator%3D+assignment+integer+c%2B%2B+is%3Aquestion I don't think these terms are too hard to come up, and position 12 in searches isn't too deep to look at. But sometimes people overlook these things. But the presentation of the question itself doesn't seem to indicate much research effort either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by providing a conversion operator from your class to `int`:

```
class Integer
{
 // ... stuff
public:
  operator int() const
  { return member_to_assign; }
};
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much for your response.I'm new to this website that's why didn't knew how to ask question properly. But at least you understood my problem. :)